# An error occurred while doing a simple flask exercise posted on the blog

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flask, server, ngrok

https://yunwoong.tistory.com/135

I am getting an error while reading and following this blog post.

The code you wrote is:

```
import json
from flask import Flask, request, make_response
 
app = Flask(__name__)
 
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def hello_there():
    slack_event = json.loads(request.data)
    if "challenge" in slack_event:
        return make_response(slack_event["challenge"], 200, {"content_type": "application/json"})
    return make_response("There are no slack request events", 404, {"X-Slack-No-Retry": 1})
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5002)
```

I wrote it in vscode on macbook m1.

When I ran this code I got a 405: method not allowed error.

Following the blog owner's advice, '@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])'
I changed it to '@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])' and ran it, but I encountered a 500 Internal Server Error.

How do I modify this code to make it work properly?

Oh, and when using ngrok in the terminal, the command should be ./ngrok instead of ngrok. Can you tell me why this is?

Comment: If a GET request is received, what content do you expect in `request.data`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

`request.data` obtains the data sent by the POST request, and the default browser access is a GET request. You need to use an API tool similar to "postman" to send a post request, and obtain different method parameters by judging the request method.such as：

```py
import json
from json import JSONDecodeError

from flask import Flask, request, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def hello_there():
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            slack_event = json.loads(request.data)
        except JSONDecodeError:
            slack_event = {}
        if "challenge" in slack_event:
            return make_response(
                slack_event["challenge"], 200, {"content_type": "application/json"}
            )
    return make_response(
        "There are no slack request events", 404, {"X-Slack-No-Retry": 1}
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=5002)
```

When using ngrok in the terminal, the system will look for the bin environment variable in the current environment, and will not use the executable file in the current directory, but use ./ngrok to execute the ngrok executable file in the current directory